# Method parameters in objects

Tags: c#

Hoping I wont get flamed for this as I've used objects for a while now but never considered this.

When declaring a method in a class i.e;

```
public class shape
{
    public int area(int basePassed, int heightPassed)
    {
       return basePassed * heightPassed;
    }
}
```

When the object is called for the main class calling it i.e:

```
 int base = 3;
 int height = 4;

 shape test = new shape();

 int areaReturned = test.area(base, height)
```

Are the parameter variables of the method 'area' of the shape class used to purely set the parameter types expected to be passed when the object is created. Or, do these variables take in a passed copy of the variables from the 'Main' class when the object method is called?

Comment: In that case they get 'copied', yes; you should read up on reference and value types in .NET. And your code won't compile, by the way. `shape` has not constructor to accept those parameters, and `base` does not exist, and `base` is an invalid name where is does exist.

Comment: There's a lot wrong with this code. First, in your `area` method, you should be returning `basePassed * heightPassed`. Second, `base` is a reserved word in C#. If you really feel the need to use it, put a `@` in front of it. Lastly, not sure what you're actually asking...

Comment: I apologies guys. I wrote this code very quickly when asking the question so I know it won't compile. Ive got the answer I was after though.

Answer (score -1):

Found this guys. Thanks all.

'Therefore, passing a value-type variable to a method means passing a copy of the variable to the method. Any changes to the parameter that take place inside the method have no affect on the original data stored in the variable.'